# What is the correct keyboard layout for the attached one

Tags: windows

What is the correct Windows keyboard layout for this keyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### What is the correct Windows keyboard layout for this keyboard?

It's an Italian keyboard:

- <kbd>Fine</kbd> translate as <kbd>End</kbd>, and
- <kbd>Canc</kbd> is short for **Cancella** which translates as <kbd>Delete</kbd>.